# How to solve equations when logarithm is the exponent?

Tags: logarithms

Here is an example problem where the logarithm is expressed as an exponent. Please help me understand this concept its not properly covered in my textbook. 
$$
3^{\log_3 (2k)} = 9
$$

Comment: Do you know the definition of $\log_ba$?

Comment: yes, but it does not refer to the logarithm when it is expressed as an exponent.

Comment: The whole point is that logarithms are inverses of exponential functions, so $a^{\log_ab}=b$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: taking the logarithm on both sides we get
$$\log_{3}{2k}\ln(3)=\ln(3^2)$$
and this is equal to
$$\log_{3}{2k}=2$$
from here we get $$3^2=2k$$
Can you finish?

Comment: I still do not understand what you did in the first step, how can you take the logarithm of an exponential logarithm?

Comment: we use that $$\ln(x^r)=r\ln(x)$$ if $x>0$

Comment: what does definition have to do with this problem? I can read the definitions on a textbook, so I would appreciate clarification.

Answer (score 0):

By *definition*, $a^{\log_a x}=x$, as $\log_a x$ is the unique number $b$ such that $a^b=x$.

Thus the equation is simply $2k=9$.

I wouldn't use the longer way of writing the equation as $3^{\log_3(2k)}=3^2$, from which we can infer $\log_3(2k)=2$ and therefore $2k=9$ by definition of logarithm.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there are logarithms in equations you usually come back to the rules of logarithms. Namely :

$\,\ln(a^b)=b\ln(a) \\a^{log_ax}=x \\ log_a(x)=b \implies a^b=x\\$

Now in your question $\,3^{\log_3 (2k)} = 9 \\2k = 9\\k=\frac92$